# Yeoman webapp generator error with sass

Tags: node.js, sass, yeoman, yeoman-generator

Followed the "Get Started" instruction of Yeoman and get the latest stable npm and bower. However I'm getting the following error when running `npm install`

```
`npm install

\> node-sass@3.2.0 install /Users/zifei/Dev/projects/Woyao-
web/node_modules/grunt-sass/node_modules/node-sass

\> node scripts/install.js

Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download
/v3.2.0/darwin-x64-45_binding.node": HTTP error 404 Not Found

\> node-sass@3.2.0 postinstall /Users/zifei/Dev/projects/Woyao-
web/node_modules/grunt-sass/node_modules/node-sass

\> node scripts/build.js

Building: /Users/zifei/.nvm/versions/io.js/v3.0.0/bin/iojs 
node_modules/pangyp/bin/node-gyp rebuild --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= 
--libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp: /Users/zifei/.node-gyp/3.0.0/common.gypi not found (cwd: /Users/zifei
/Dev/projects/Woyao-web/node_modules/grunt-sass/node_modules/node-sass) 
while reading includes of binding.gyp while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/Users/zifei/Dev/projects
/Woyao-web/node_modules/grunt-sass/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules
/pangyp/lib/configure.js:345:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit 
(internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 14.4.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/zifei/.nvm/versions/io.js/v3.0.0/bin/iojs" 
"/Users/zifei/Dev/projects/Woyao-web/node_modules/grunt-sass/node_modules
/node-sass/node_modules/pangyp/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild" "--libsass_ext=" 
"--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/zifei/Dev/projects/Woyao-web/node_modules/grunt-
sass/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v3.0.0
gyp ERR! pangyp -v v2.2.1
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed
npm ERR! Darwin 14.4.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/zifei/.nvm/versions/io.js/v3.0.0/bin/iojs" "/Users
/zifei/.nvm/versions/io.js/v3.0.0/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v3.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.13.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! node-sass@3.2.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@3.2.0 postinstall script 'node 
scripts/build.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the node-sass package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-sass
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/zifei/Dev/projects/Woyao-web/npm-debug.log`
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what is happening here, but the issue is that your computer is unable to build a native module. You can know this because the error is coming from `gyp` which is the [native binary builder for node](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp).

What I'd do in your case is try with another version. I see here you're using io.js 3.0.0 which is not necessarily the most stable version out there. I'd suggest trying with either another io.js version or using node.js 0.12 until the official node 4.0 release.

You can also just update npm and retry. Sometime it can be a race condition issue.